# UICollectionViewCell background colour not modified after adding gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So long story short - trying to implement **whatsapp** style reply to messages feature.

- User long taps (holds) on a chat bubble
- Chat bubble and cell background color changes indicating selection
- Present an action bar asking user if they want to reply to the message
- If user presses reply, restore the cell background color and chat bubble color to default

I am achieving this with a `UILongTapGesture` which I am adding to the whole collection view

**Problem**:
The gesture **recognises** the **tap** **point** and the **index** **path**. The accurate index path is also printed when I use print(indexPath.item). The problem is I am **unable** to modify the properties of the cell that I access using this index path. I believe I am accessing the cell in the right way. I want to change the background color of the cell and the chat bubble once user taps on a cell but nothing happens

Here is the code:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
        generator.prepare()

        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
            
            let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.collectionView)
            if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint) {
                let cell = collectionView(self.collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as? ChatCell
                //DOES NOT WORK
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Actions", message: "Press reply to reply to selected messages", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                
                let replyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Reply", style: .default) { (_) in
                    //do stuff here
                    alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in
                    cell?.backgroundColor = .clear
                    alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
                alertController.addAction(replyAction)
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I am adding the gesture recognizer:

```
        let longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress))
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
        longPressGesture.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

Here is my collection View cell:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(bubbleView)
        bubbleView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        bubbleView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 16, right: 0))
        bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        bubbleConstraintLeading = bubbleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16)
        bubbleConstraintTrailing = bubbleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        
        bubbleView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.anchor(top: bubbleView.topAnchor, leading: bubbleView.leadingAnchor, bottom: bubbleView.bottomAnchor, trailing: bubbleView.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 4, left: 16, bottom: 4, right: 16))
        
        addSubview(timestampLabel)
        timestampLabel.anchor(top: bubbleView.bottomAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: 4, right: 0))
        timestampConstraintLeading = timestampLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 24)
        timestampConstraintTrailing = timestampLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -24)
    }
```

Comment: Are you adding the gesture recognizer on UICollectionView ?

Comment: @Stamenkovski Yes I am doing that. It is a collection view controller so I am basically doing;

Comment: let longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress))
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
        longPressGesture.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

Comment: I literally recreated your example and it's working as it should, are you sure you don't have some holder view that covers your entire cell ?

Comment: Oh thats weird, well the background color of my cells are transparent so only the chat bubble is colored (Obv). So the cells naturally take the color of my underlying collection view background color

Comment: can you try like this for example:
cell.chatBubbleView.backgroundColor = color

Comment: @Stamenkovski I shall post the code for my collection view cell

Comment: @Stamenkovski Yes already tried that. None of the properties are being modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cell = collectionView(self.collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as? ChatCell
```

you should not call the DataSource method like this.

If you want to get the cell at given `IndexPath`, you should use the `UICollectionView` function

```
self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) as? ChatCell
```

Comment: Works like a charm. May I know why the function I first called didn't work?

Comment: Well the function you used is from UICollectionViewDataSource delegate, so the UICollectionView will call this function when it needs to deque/reuse cell as you are scrolling. It will not return cell when you call it directly as you did.